# Use of Postgis raster datasets for visualization and generation of GeoJSON

Tags: boundless-suite

I am currently using Boundless/OpenGeo 4.02 with PostGIS 2.1. I would like a little advice on the development of specific functionalities. I am currently attempting to begin with a number of GeoTiffs, and would ultimately like to use them to for display in an OpenLayers map, and also provide the ability for users to draw a polygon (or enter coordinates) on this map and extract a GeoJSON file of pixel or point values from the underlying raster. My thinking is to import the geotiffs as PostGIS raster files, open them as a data source in OpenGeo server, and then display them in the OpenLayers map. Users can then query the map by drawing a polygon, which would query the PostGIS table and return the selected pixel values formatted as GeoJSON.

First, does this sound like a reasonable avenue to take given the required functionality?

Second, where can I find the most up to date documentation on correctly reading PostGIS rasters into OpenGeo server? I have seen references to Image Mosaic JDBC, but can't seem to find how I build in this capability into the version of OpenGeo (4.02) that I am currently using....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately using PostGIS rasters with GeoServer requires a mosaicing plug-in (Image Mosaic JDBC) that doesn't ship with OpenGeo Suite. It is much more common for users to use the built in mosaic support [1] that just works with the GeoTiff files directly from the file system.

Once you have the GeoTiff layer set up in GeoServer you can utilize the Web Coverage Service [2] to get at the raw raster data for an area of interest. Unfortunately the WCS won't give you back GeoJSON but there are other formats you can probably work with.

Of use will be the latest documentation for building web applications [3]. You can browse the entire suite of docs from:

http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/

[1] http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/data/raster/imagemosaic.html

[2] http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/services/wcs/index.html

[3] http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/index.html